# Adding Constraint to Multiple Columns With Status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `events_attendees` which has the following columns and then some ea_no, c_no, e_no, ea_status.

I want to add a constraint which validate unique row for column c_no, e_no with ea_status = 1.

Our system uses the status field for removal so there might be several ea_status = 0 records for the same c_no, e_no but the constraint should allow for an insert as long as there isn't a matching e_no, c_no, ea_status = 1.

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Could you help me a little more please. I've got, is that right?

ALTER TABLE `events_attendees` ADD check `check_event_c_no_dup`(e_no, c_no, ea_status = 1);

Comment: read this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your table name and column name into the code

```
CREATE TABLE CheckTbl (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int);
GO
CREATE FUNCTION CheckFnctn( @col2 int, @col3 int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
   SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) FROM CheckTbl
   where col2=@col2 and col3=@col3 and col4=1
   RETURN @retval
END;
GO
ALTER TABLE CheckTbl
ADD CONSTRAINT chkRowCount CHECK (dbo.CheckFnctn(col2,col3) = 1 );
GO
```